# How do I use Xamarin.Essentials MediaPicker with MVVM and DataBinding

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to capture a photo in my app and as this needs to be implemented on different pages I need it to work within MVVM architecture. It works perfectly fine when I test it on the Camera page code behind, but as soon as I implement DataBinding and MVVM, the Emulator camera fails to initialize. I don't get any build or deployment errors and have no idea where to start looking. The documentation isn't much help. The images captured needs to be saved and reused each time the  app is opened - something to keep in mind perhaps.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamCam.Views;
using MvvmHelpers;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace XamCam.ViewModels
{
    public class CameraViewModels : BaseViewModel
    {
        public CameraViewModels()
        {
            TakePhoto = new Command(OnTakePhoto);
        }

        public ICommand TakePhoto { get; }

        private Image image; // = new Image();
        public Image CamImage
        {
            get => image;
            set
            {
                if (image == value)
                    return;
                image = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        async void OnTakePhoto()
        {
            var result = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

            if (result != null)
            {
                var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

                image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my View XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:XamCam.ViewModels" 
             x:DataType="viewmodels:CameraViewModels"
             x:Class="XamCam.Views.Camera"
             BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:CameraViewModels/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BindingContext="CameraViewModel">
            <Label Text="Welcome to The XamCam!" />
            <Button Text="Take Photo"
                    Command="{Binding TakePhoto}"/>
            <Image BindingContext="{Binding CamImage}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I suspect that it has something to do with my `CamImage` property but I am very new to this and I am not sure if this is the correct way to bind a media object.

Comment: here is a big hint from the MediaPicker docs: "All methods must be called on the UI thread because permission checks and requests are automatically handled by Xamarin.Essentials."

Comment: Why would a command be fired on a non-UI thread @Jason?

Comment: maybe I'm wrong - but I don't see it documented that a command is always on the main thread.

Comment: @Jason I picked up on that because my knowledge is very beginner level I wasn't sure if and how this is affected by MVVM. My understanding is that it still runs on the main thread but the business logic is simply encapsulated elsewhere. Not sure if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect that it has something to do with my CamImage property but I am very new to this and I am not sure if this is the correct way to bind a media object.

I suggest you can add `ImageSource1` property, not `Image` property in CameraViewModels.

```
public class CameraViewModels : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CameraViewModels()
    {
        TakePhoto = new Command(OnTakePhoto);
    }

    public ICommand TakePhoto { get; }

    private ImageSource image;
    public ImageSource CamImage
    {
        get => image;
        set
        {
            if (image == value)
                return;
            image = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CamImage");
        }
    }

    async void OnTakePhoto()
    {
        var result = await Xamarin.Essentials.MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

        if (result != null)
        {
            var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

            CamImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

<ContentPage
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:CameraViewModels />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to The XamCam!" />
        <Button Command="{Binding TakePhoto}" Text="Take Photo" />
        <Image Source="{Binding CamImage}" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: It makes a lot more sense this way but for some odd reason the camera is still not launching. I'm starting to wonder if the camera only launches with click events and not commands. Not sure why.

Comment: @JC_vd_Merwe_03 According to your code,  you launch camera by Button.click, I binding TakePhoto command to Button.command, I can open camera and have no problems, so do you try my code? Still having any questions?

Comment: I tried your code, like I said in my comment the camera is still not launching. The issue must be elsewhere because by all indications it should be working. Going to try in a new project and see if that makes a difference. Will let you know.

Comment: @JC_vd_Merwe_03 It is so strange, because I use my code, every thing works fine, and I can launch camera successfully. If you have any update, please let me know.